# does program counter generates physical or logical address?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

so i was reading about memory addresses and confuse about what address does the program counter store. each thread has there own program counter value, so does these program counters hold addresses respective to the program or do they hold actual physical memory addresses.
because in operating system concepts by `abraham silbrschatz` it's saying cpu generates the logical addresses, and cpu gets those addresses from program counter. so it's seems like program counters of threads hold the logical address!

can i get a heads up with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU doesn't generate logical addresses, it finds the physical address corresponding to a logical address by using the page tables. The CPU never 'generates' addresses. The CPU is a dead machine made of circuits that blindly execute instructions. The CPU has an architecture (x64, ARM, RISC-V or others) and it is its architecture which determines the format of the binary instructions it understands. It is the programmer that generates the instructions using input/output mechanisms like keyboard, mouse and the screen.

The program counter contains logical addresses. The program counter is a physical CPU register which is a small memory. The thread is an abstract OS construct. The OS programmers write structures in main memory to keep track of each thread like the Process Control Block (PCB) and several lists of threads for each different thread state like running, ready, waiting for IO, etc. It is the PCB that holds the program counter of a thread that's not currently running. On thread switch, the current program counter is saved in the PCB of that thread and the PCB of another is read to change the thread running on that core. The job of the OS is to balance threads between available cores to give the impression that each thread is running concurently.

The program counter's value is thus translated to a physical address by crossing the page tables.

Comment: so does the program counter contains the logical addresses that was given to the program while compile time!

Comment: Not necessarily. The executable after compilation contains a logical start address (the first instruction of the program) but this is a suggestion for the OS loader that can change due to ASLR (random starting address). Most code in executables today is position independent. Stack memory is accessed using a relative offset from the stack register and the data segment using a relative offset from the program counter. The heap is dynamically allocated (while the program is running) so the OS can just return an absolute 64 bits pointer to anywhere in the logical address space.

Comment: That way, there is no need to contain logical addresses in the executable itself. The memory to access the data is relative to something and the instructions are randomly placed in the address space somewhere and executed in order of appearance with only jumps and conditionnal instructions that can change the flow of execution.

Comment: For more details read one of my recent answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74354589/what-would-be-an-example-of-position-dependent-code/74355602#74355602

Comment: Thank you so much. i've read your answer, and you've explained so well. and thank you again for clearing my concept.